# Android ListView-Header takes in first position (position(0))

Tags: android, arrays, listview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a ListView with a header. I know that header will take `position == 0` in my ListView.

In my Array I have 3 Strings. If the Header takes the first Position. There are 2 left for my Arrays.

Normally you would write:

```
if (array[position] == array[0]) {
    Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected the first Array-String, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

but I have to write this:

```
if (array[position] == array[1]) {
    Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected the first Array-String, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

However, since Header takes the first Position, I getting a Force Close in my app when I click on the third entry.

I'd be thankful for every single answer to my question.

This is the whole Click Listener

```
private void addDrawerItems() {
     final String[] array = { "Earn Coins", "Get Likes", "Logout"};
     mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

     View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
     mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header, "null", false);
     mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

     mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             if(array[position]==array[1]){
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected Earn Coins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                 UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
             }else if(array[position]==array[2]){
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected Get Likes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, GetLikesActivity.class);
                 UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
             }else if(array[position]==array[3]){
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected Logout!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                 UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
             }else{
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this,"Whatever..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }

         }
     });
 }
```

The Error I get is this:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
    at de.enesak.likelounge.UserAreaActivity$1.onItemClick(UserAreaActivity.java:59)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you are mixing the `ListView` position/lenght with your `array` length

**Failure**

As you informed in your question, you have a Header in your `ListView`. Then, probably, your list view has following positions:

- [0] - Header
- [1] - Item1
- [2] - Item2
- [3] - Item3

However, you variable `array` probably has crated with the Items only. So, your array is like:

- [0] - Item1
- [1] - Item2
- [2] - Item3

This way, if(array[position]==array[3]) line below will produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `array` does not have element [3].

**Fix**

You can fix your code in different ways, like:

- Create an `array` with `lenght == 4` and ignore position [0].

  This is not good. Your array will match with ListView position. However, you have a unnecessary memory being used.
- Change your if/else

Just always consider that `array` goes from 0 to 2 (and not from 0 to 3). It does not have 4 elements like your ListView.

```
if(array[position]==array[0]){
     // code
} else if(array[position]==array[1]){
    // code
} if(array[position]==array[2]){
    // code
} else {
    // code
}
```

**Correct Solution For Your Issue**

You just need to consult the position clicked by user and take the action that you want... You don't need to compare with your array. So, update your code like below:

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          switch (position) {
            case 1: {
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected Earn Coins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                 UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                 break;
            }
            case 2: {
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected Get Likes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, GetLikesActivity.class);
                 UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                 break;
            }
            case 3: {
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this, "You've selected Logout!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
                 UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                 break;
             }
             default:
                // Header
                 Toast.makeText(UserAreaActivity.this,"Whatever..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 break;
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer. By using your Code I dont get the Error anymore, but now it doesnt matter what item I click, every case gets true.

Comment: Sorry.. I forgot to insert break... I' updated the answer

Comment: Perfect! With the break line it works. Thank you so much. Could you maybe tell me why your method works and mine doesnt? Would be really helpfull for me.

Comment: Sure.. Just give me some minutes and I'll update the answer